# Magento new products are not showing in homepage

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In magento I want to show new products in my home page. So to do that I have searched many blogs and forums. From all of them I have got that by using

`{{block type="catalog/product_new" block_id="new.products" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}`

in CMS -> Homepage content I will get the new products. But still I am not getting any products. Also I have tried to change the date active . But it is not showing any products. So can someone kindly tell me what is the issue here? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In default Magento implementation of `catalog/product_new` block the rules are:

- the product should be visible in catalog
- the product should have both `news_from_date` and `news_to_date` attributes set to some values
- attribute  `news_from_date` works till end of today's date (23:59:59) and attribute `news_to_date` works from the begin of today's date (00:00:00)

When there be at least one product that meet that requirements the block will be rendered. Also flushing your cache and reindexing data could help as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you end up here, there is another simple fix to try:

System -> Index Management

and select them all (even if they are indicating "Green, no re-index needed" and force them to reindex.

This solved my empty getSize() problem, which in turn, allowed the Special and New database requests to find the products, fulfill the "if" conditions and properly render.

Answer (score 0):

try this
  write following code in  cms->page->design tab->Layout Update XML

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured" template="catalog/product/new.phtml">
        </block>
    </reference>
```

you have to add new.phtml file in "app\design\frontend\default\default\template\catalog\product"

write following code in new.phtml file

```
<?php

/******************

        //Recently Added Products

    ************************/
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->setVisibility(array(2,3,4))                   
                    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');

?>


    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div id="block">
        <div class="text">Recently Added Products
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl("recent_added"); ?>" class="link"> View more &#187; </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php foreach($_productCollection as $_product) : ?>
        <div class="grid">

            <div class="imgholder" >
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" 
                    class="product-image">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" 
                    alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
            </div>

            <strong><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>" style="color:#039;"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a></strong>

            <p><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?></p>

            <div class="price">
             <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
            </div>

        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: you have to put your phtml file in app\design\frontend\default\default\template\catalog\product

Answer (score 0):

You can also display it using Widget. I mean by adding widget in CMS homepage.

Answer (score 0):

I had this probalem and spoke to an agent who took control of it for me and worked it out as explaining it didnt help. You need to put all the nav categories into the highest root category (so all categories will look like subcategories of the first root which you cannot delete. They must not be or be stemming from any paralell root categories. Then refresh your index and the category items will be there in the nav menu.